# var value with integer is not assigned in while loop

Tags: javascript, protractor

i am trying to get a pagenumber values from the method getPageNumber(), where the page number is getting printed in console. But that value is not used in While loop. Even if i try to print pageNum, it returns promise.
Refer console output.
[image]

```js
it('TS-06, should able to navigate to Manage Users Screen',function(){
        clientAdminPortal.clickMenuInSideBar("User Management");

        manageUsers.at().then(function() {
            console.log("---> Navigated to Manage Users Screen");

        });

        expect(manageUsers.isVisible(manageUsers.searchTxtBox)).toBeTruthy();
    });

 it('TS-10, verify Activate Button is viewed for all users',function(){
        var i=1;
        var check=false;
        var pageNum=manageUsers.getPageNumber();
        while(i<pageNum){
        console.log("check");
        i++;
 }
});

this.getPageNumber=function(){
        return this.pgnumCount.then(function(number){
            console.log(number.length);
            return number.length;
        });
    };
```

Comment: `while(i<pageNum){console.log("check");}` That will block forever.

Comment: Remember Javascript is single-threaded.

Comment: @connexo - Well, no, but there's one main thread on browsers. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder If you take web workers out of the equation, my knowledge is that JS is single-threaded. I'd be curious to learn if that changed.

Comment: @connexo - Yes, if you take other threads off the table, there will be only one thread, ipso facto. But if you leave other threads on the table... The *language* is not single-threaded. Most implementations (not all) have a single thread per realm (sometimes shared across realms), but again, that's most, not all. JavaScript on the JVM, for instance, is fully multi-threaded.

Comment: @connexo - Node.js has one thread for event loop and your code execution, but it has thread pool in background (usually it uses 4 threads). If you spawn workers, they will be executed in these threads.

Comment: my concern is value for pageNum is returned as promise. i have added console inside while to check it. also i missed to add i++ inside while loop but in actual i have added it

Comment: while loop is not getting executed. i is checked with pageNum which is returning as promise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `this.getPageNumber()` return a promise,  you have to consume promise within `then()` as below:

```
it('TS-10, verify Activate Button is viewed for all users', function () {
    var i = 1;
    var check = false;

    manageUsers.getPageNumber().then(function (pageNum) {
        while (i < pageNum) {
            console.log("check");
            i++;
        }
    });

});
```